# How to apply the TapGestureRecognizer in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gesture

I have a Picture A. When I *single* tap it, it should show Picture C. But if I *double* tap it, it should show Picture D.

Below is my code in XAML:

```xml
<Image Source="pictureA.JPG"
       VerticalOptions="Start"
       HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Below is my code in cs:

```cs
int tapCount;
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var imageSender = (Image)sender;
    if (tapCount == 1)
    {
        imageSender.Source = "pictureC.png";
    }
    else if (tapCount == 2)
    {
        imageSender.Source = "pictureD.JPG";
    }
}
```

But above code does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a good article with a demo: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Comment: I read the article, I follow the tutorial on that page but one the picture was double click it will show the first picture, if more than double click it show the same picture which not able go to the other picture.

Comment: You are not reseting the tapCount so your image will change only if tapCount is 1 or 2.